# Why am I having to double cast here?

Tags: vb.net, generics, inheritance, .net-3.5, casting

I have inheritance structure: `Foo` implements `IGraphNode` inherits `IGraphItem`.

`Foo`, `IGraphItem`/`IGraphNode`, and the implementation for `IGraphItem`/`IGraphNode` all reside in separate assemblies. I am using an inversion of control container, so the project I'm working in has a reference to the first two (`Foo` and `IGraphItem`/`IGraphNode`), but not the implementation of `IGraphItem`/`IGraphNode`. I also have Option Strict on as it is required for this project (turning if off didn't fix the problem). I'm using .NET 3.5.

I am passing a `IGraphItem` around and I have code that looks like this:

```
Public Sub ProcessItem(of IGraphItem)(item As IGraphItem)
    If TypeOf item Is Foo Then
        Dim f1 = CType(item, Foo) 'Compiler error
        Dim f2 = DirectCast(item, Foo) 'Compiler error

        'This is what I'm currently having to do. It works.
        Dim f = CType(CType(item, IGraphNode), Foo)

        'Do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

Any idea why I'm having to do this? I should add that `TryCast` works, but since we've just confirmed that `item`'s type is `Foo`, I don't see why I can't `DirectCast` it. Shouldn't it just let me and throw an exception if I'm wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Not sure what's going on but it compiles and works also on runtime. What compiler error do you get?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I get a `Value of type 'IGraphItem' cannot be converted to 'Foo'` error. Updated question to add that I'm using .NET 3.5.

Comment: When i change the target framework to 3.5 i'm getting many exceptions. But still no problem to cast item(which is ob type `IGraphNode`) to type `Foo`.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I left out in the code that the type of `item` is `IGraphItem`.

Comment: Not a problem either. IGraphItem and IGraphNode are both in different assemblies then Foo(but both in the same). Not sure whether or not that matters.

Comment: I believe I figured it out. In simplifying my code example, I left out the subroutines is declared to be `(Of IGraphItem)` (see code sample above). Taking that away solved the problem. Now why exactly that was the problem, I'm still not sure. Anyone want to write a good answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code compiles without a problem, even when target framework is 3.5.

The problem with your current code is that you've defined a generic method whereas `IGraphItem` is not the type of your interface but the generic type `T` which can be any type. But it cannot be another type than `T` and you're trying to cast it to type `Foo`.

If you would change your method signature to anything else it would work, for instance:

```
Public Sub ProcessItem(of IGraphItm)(item As IGraphItem)
```

I assume that you're somehow "shadowing" the type `IGraphItem` of your interface with the generic type `IGraphItem` in this method.

It would also work if you would explicitely tell the compiler that `item As IGraphItem` actually is a `item As YourNamespace.IGraphItem`.

<sub>I'm sure Jon or Eric could explain it better, but maybe it's helpful anyway ;)</sub>